# Swift cannot access ObjC interface property defined as id<Protocol>

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an ObjC interface that defines property `controller` like this:

```
@protocol STXFeedPhotoCellDelegate;
@protocol STXLikesCellDelegate;
@protocol STXCaptionCellDelegate;
@protocol STXCommentCellDelegate;
@protocol STXUserActionDelegate;

@interface STXFeedTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL insertingRow;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <STXFeedPhotoCellDelegate, STXLikesCellDelegate, STXCaptionCellDelegate, STXCommentCellDelegate, STXUserActionDelegate> controller;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *comments;

- (instancetype)initWithController:(id<STXFeedPhotoCellDelegate, STXLikesCellDelegate, STXCaptionCellDelegate, STXCommentCellDelegate, STXUserActionDelegate>)controller;

- (void)reloadAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

I have added this header file to the bridging header.

I then define a subclass in Swift that subclasses `STXFeedTableViewDelegate`. However, this Swift class cannot access the `super.controller` property. It can, however, access any of the other properties of the superclass `STXFeedTableViewDelegate`. I suspect the reason behind that is because the `controller` property is defined as `id<Protocol>`.

I'd be thankful is someone can provide a way to make Swift recognise this property from ObjC class.

**Update**: with Swift code:

```
class PostTableViewDelegate: STXFeedTableViewDelegate {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let controller = self.controller
        let controller2 = super.controller
        //more class code below
```

`let controller = self.controller` fails with `PostTableViewDelegate does not have a member called controller`

`let controller2 = super.controller` fails with `STXFeedTableViewDelegate does not have a member called controller`

Comment: Update your question with relevant Swift code and point out the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy done, see above.